# How to detect network disconnect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

I working on a network application for Mac OS X 10.7/10.6. And I need to detect network problem . Another words I need to detect when no internet connection. I tried to add some method with a timer which connect to server, and show message if no results. But I need more realtime solution.
Is there some system notifications about network disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

if you use nsstreams, then do

header:

```
@interface CrestronClient : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate> {

    NSInputStream *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream;

}
@end
```

.m File:

init values usually in a connect method or did load

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, 192.168.1.1, 46651, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

    unsigned char connectByteArray1[] = {
        0x01, 0x00, 0x07, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x40
    };

    [outputStream write:connectByteArray1 maxLength:sizeof(connectByteArray1)];
```

then your delegate method:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    switch (streamEvent) 
    {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        {
            DDLogVerbose(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        }

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if(!rawData) {
                rawData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)theStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {
                [rawData initWithBytes:buf length:len];                
            } else {
                DDLogVerbose(@"no buffer!");
            }
        }   
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        {
            if ([theStream isKindOfClass:[NSInputStream class]]) {
                NSString* address = [self getAddress];
                NSString* myIPAdress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IP Address: %@", address];

                //[cClient updateRequest];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cant Connect" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cant connect to server: %@, Make sure you are connected to the proper wireless network.  Your Ip Address is %@",CCV.ipAddress,myIPAdress] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Reconnect", nil];

                [alert show];
                [alert release];            
            }
            break;   
        }

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        {
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [theStream release];
            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        {
            //DDLogVerbose(@"has space available");
            break;
        }

        case NSStreamEventNone:
        {
            DDLogVerbose(@"none");
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            DDLogVerbose(@"Unknown event");
        }
    }
}
```

you can see that there are cases for connected, not connected, disconnected
this is what you need

Comment: Thank you! It's a good solution in case when we have connected to some host. But what to do when we launch application and not connected to host yet and after that unplug the network cable or turn off WiFi connection?

Comment: if im on the wrong wifi network(meaning i cant get to my target ip) the NSStreamEventErrorOccurred triggers cuz it cant connect and thats why i have that alert in there to "reconnect" or retry the connection